# Create set from pandas series with NaN's

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, series

I'm using pandas to clean some data files and validate the content. In the validation, I compare the content of each column with a set of expected values by

```
for col_name, expected in expected_dict.items():
    col_values = set(df[col_name])
    if not col_values.issubset(expected):
        raise ValueError(str(col_values - expected),'in',col_name)
```

I'm running into some unexpected behavior with NaN's. Specifically,  `set(series)` treats each NaN as a unique element. I figured out a solution, which is `set(series.unique())`.

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,1,None,3,None])
set(s) ## Produces {nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, nan}
set(s.unique()) ## Produces {nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

My question is really why this is the behavior is encountered? I suspect it is related to the representation of NaN's in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the properties of NaN is that NaN != NaN, unlike all other numbers. However, the implementation of set first checks to see if id(x) matches the existing member at a hash index before it tries to insert a new one. If you have two objects with different ids that both have the value NaN, you'll get two entries in the set. If they both have the same id, they collapse into a single entry